# VBA, NumberFormat when pasting an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following vba code, but I want to paste it giving the format of dd-mm-yyyy.

```
Worksheets("stack").Range("M" & LastRowM + 1 & ":" & Cells(LastRowM + UBound(PasteArr, 1) - 1, 18).Address).Value = PasteArr
```

I've tried:

```
   Worksheets("stack").Range("M" & LastRowM + 1 & ":" & Cells(LastRowM + UBound(PasteArr, 1) - 1, 18).Address).Value = PasteArr.Numberformat = ('dd-mm-yyyy')
```

I am unsure on the format of this. Where do I put numberformat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on a different line, two actions:

```
Worksheets("stack").Range("M" & LastRowM + 1 & ":" & Cells(LastRowM + UBound(PasteArr, 1) - 1, 18).Address).Value = PasteArr
Worksheets("stack").Range("M" & LastRowM + 1 & ":" & Cells(LastRowM + UBound(PasteArr, 1) - 1, 18).Address).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
```

But we can shorten it a little with `With` and `Resize`

```
With Worksheets("stack").Range("M" & LastRowM + 1).resize(Ubound(pasteArr,1),18)
    .Value = PasteArr
    .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
End With
```

Comment: anyway this can just be pasted for one column of the array? Or does this change the date of the whole array data?

Comment: currently all of it as that is what your code is attempting to do.

Comment: If you want only one column then change the second line in the first grouping to only include that column.